# Parse/load Huge XML file with spark

Tags: python, xml, apache-spark, hive

I have an XML file with the following setup.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SomeRoottag>
 <row Id="47513849" PostTypeId="1" />
 <row Id="4751323" PostTypeId="4" />
 <row Id="475546" PostTypeId="1" />
 <row Id="47597" PostTypeId="2" />
</SomeRoottag>
```

I parse the file and save it as Hive table with the following code.

```
df = sqlContext.read.format('xml').option("rowTag","SomeRoottag").load("/tmp/xmlfile.xml")
flat=df.withColumn("rows2",explode(df.row)).select("rows2.*")
flat.write.format("parquet").saveAsTable("xml_table")
```

With my test data (10mb) everything is working fine, but when i load the big file (>50G) it fails.
It seems that the spark JVM tries to load the whole file an fails because it is only 20G big.

What is the best way to work with an file like that?

**Update:**

if i do the following i do not receive any data:

```
df = (sqlContext.read.format('xml').option("rowTag", "row").load("/tmp/someXML.xml"))
df.printSchema()
df.show()
```

**output:**

```
root

++
||
++
++
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `SomeRoottag` as a `rowTag`. It instructs Spark to use a whole document as a single row. Instead:

```
df = (sqlContext.read.format('xml')
    .option("rowTag", "row")
    .load("/tmp/xmlfile.xml"))
```

Now there is no need to explode either:

```
df.write.format("parquet").saveAsTable("xml_table")
```

**Edit**:

Considering your edit you are affected by a known bug. Please see [Self-closing tags are not supported as top-level rows #92](https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml/issues/92). It doesn't look like there is any current progress on solving that, so you may have to:

- Make a PR yourself to fix this thing.
- Parse file manually. If elements are always single line, it can be easily done with `udf`.

  ```
  from pyspark.sql.functions import col, udf
  from lxml import etree

  @udf("struct<id: string, postTypeId: string>")
  def parse(s):
      try:
          attrib = etree.fromstring(s).attrib
          return attrib.get("Id"), attrib.get("PostTypeId")
      except:
          pass

  (spark.read.text("/tmp/someXML.xml")
      .where(col("value").rlike("^\\s*<row "))
      .select(parse("value").alias("value"))
      .select("value.*")
      .show())

  # +--------+----------+
  # |      id|postTypeId|
  # +--------+----------+
  # |47513849|         1|
  # | 4751323|         4|
  # |  475546|         1|
  # |   47597|         2|
  # +--------+----------+
  ```

Comment: Works for me! I was able to process the wikipedia dump xml file using this method.